# How to Release Objects initiated in the ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am filling some Objects from my View Controller using the following Method :

```
        -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
            {

            }
```

What's the best way to release the Objects?I want to release all the used Object when my View closes.

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should release them **after** your view has disappeared, not before, otherwise you may see some strange effects if your view disappears with animation...

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  // release here...    
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect instruction

Answer (score 2):

release them here

```
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {

 }
```